# Javascript: How can I replace empty space with comma?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace html entity `&nbsp;` with a comma.

Html string : `2&nbsp;077 Ft`

```
//existing script - not working - adding comma after every second character
txt = txt.replace(/(\d{2})/g,"$1,")
```

I want an out put like

```
txt = 2,077 Ft
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var string = '2&nbsp;077 Ft';
string = string.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ',');

var modifiedElem = document.getElementById('modified');
modified.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<div id="original">2&nbsp;077 Ft</div>
<div id="modified"></div>
```

This will replace all occurances of '&nbsp' in desired string.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the working example. Please take a look since it does work.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Have you tried using `string.replace("&nbsp;", ",");`?</del>

Edit:as pointed out in the comments it only does the first instance. To get over this you need to use regex.
e.g.: `string.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ",");`

Comment: This is true and will work but just for the first occurance of &nbsp in string.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't able to test it since i was on phone.